# Distribute an edit text to many TextViews

Tags: java, android

i'm new to Android programming, i want to creating an android apps that need user input in **MainActivity** then display the username in another activity. i planned create 5 more activity to display the username.
this is the **MainActivity** :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Quiz1Activity.class);
            getMenuInflater().toString();
            sendName();
            startActivity(intent);
        }});
}

public void sendName(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Quiz1Activity.class);
    EditText inputnama = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputnama);
    intent.putExtra("username", message);
}
```

and this is new1Activity

```
Intent username = getIntent();
String username1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("username1");
```

i used the same code to another new Activity but it don't display anything.
can anyone explain to me what's wrong?

Comment: don't create new object just put data in first object of Intent

Comment: A somewhat easier solution would be to just store the entered username in `SharedPreferences` and loading it from the said SharedPreferences in every other activity. Cuts out all of the intent-based passing of the said parameter as well... however, it's up to you or the client to decide whether that's a privacy issue or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 EditText inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputnama);    

 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if(inputName != null){
            String message = inputName.getText().toString();

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("prefName", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("username", message);
            editor.apply();
            editor.commit();

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Quiz1Activity.class);
        }

    }});
```

**In QuizActivity and other activities**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("prefName", 0);
String userName = sharedPreferences.getString("username", "");
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, you should add some explanation with your code. Consider future users that may come. Also, don't simply provide code, explain the problem.

Comment: what is this `message` that's being passed in as an extra?

Comment: it work to Quiz1Activity, but still not displayed in other QuizActivity

Comment: @SaifulKA how many buttons you have in MainActivity. From which activity you are going to QuizActivity

Comment: @MinnuKaAnae i have 1 EditText and 1 Button in MainActivity, then i want to display the result in each TextView on Quiz1Activity - Quiz5Activity

Comment: @SaifulKA how can you do that. there is no way to do that.

Comment: i get intent from first activity to second activity, then using .putExtra to new intent and get it in third activity

Comment: @SaifulKA  check my updated answer. you should use sharedpreferences for that.

Answer (score 0):

store values in Intent;

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Quiz1Activity.class);
  EditText inputnama = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputnama);
  intent.putExtra("username", inputnama.getText().toString() );
```

get values using Intent;

```
String username1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
```

Comment: I have added enough description dude....I don't think I have to add more description for understand this topic.Well thanks for your attention

Comment: @Nathan this answer actually explains very well how to send/receive extras via `Intent`s. Not much "descriptive text" needed there, because the OP is simply not starting the right intent - he's calling a method that creates a local intent, but runs the intent from the caller method - the `onClick()` method which is shadowing it. His `sendName()` implementation is sort of dead code because it does nothing but creating a local object which isn't used anywhere.

Comment: @Shark I am not saying it's wrong - the question of the TO is "can anyone explain to me what's wrong?". This answer is great, but it doesn't explain at all what was wrong in the previous code. The objective isn't to provide the one asking a question with an all-made answer (tho most of the askers want it). Well, I'll replace my comment with the default one.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @Nathan while i do understand that, looking at the basics, the answer to the question "can anyone explain to me what is wrong" isn't done with any code, it's a simple "your code doesn't work" or more exactly "what you're doing in the `sendName()` method isn't being used anywhere and the username itself isn't being passed as an extra because it's not modifying a global variable instead of using two local variables sharing a same name" which is also useless for future readers that have non-zero debugging or programming experience.It can be closed as "Off-Topic > Simple typographical error".

Comment: @Shark I agree, and it **should** probably be considered as such: the underlying answer here is about variables visibility. That should appear in the answer IMO.

Comment: fair enough, up to Vishal whether he adds it or not :)

Answer (score 0):

If i understood the question correctly you need this when starting your activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("userName", userName);
startActivity(intent);
```

and to get the name in the new activity:

```
getIntent().getExtras().getString("userName");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this clicklistener.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new 
                Intent(MainActivity.this,Quiz1Activity.class);
                getMenuInflater().toString();
                EditText inputnama = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputnama);
                intent.putExtra("username", inputnama.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }});
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, you should add some explanation with your code. Consider future users that may come. Also, don't simply provide code, explain the problem.

Comment: what is this `message` that's being passed in as an extra?

Answer (score 0):

In your `onClick` method, you declare your :

`Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Quiz1Activity.class);`.

Then in `sendName()`, you have :

`Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Quiz1Activity.class);`.

You should understand that these two intents are not the same, they are two differents objects. The modifications on one won't affect the other.

So your `intent` in `onClick` wasn't modified. What you want to do is to return the modified intent from `sendName`, something like `startIntent(sendName());`.

Additionally, you could just pass `intent` as parameter in `sendName`.

Comment: passing the `Intent` to the `sendName()` method sounds like a decent idea. Or moving the `startActivity(intent);` in the end of `sendName()` also works.